# How to set the focus on a user control item in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a WPF app that uses different instances of a User Control; when the user clicks a button on the main window I need to set the focus on the textbox inside the currently active instance of the user control.

Which is the best way to set the focus on that child item?

Comment: Duplicate of [WPF - Set Focus when a button is clicked - No Code Behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204063/wpf-set-focus-when-a-button-is-clicked-no-code-behind)

Comment: This question does not specify that he doesn't want it in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

```
child.Focus();
```

or

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, 0).Focus(); // you might want to test it for nulls
```