# How to set autofocus only in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, autofocus

Is it possible, to set the autofocus to the textbox in my xaml file?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.Test1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Height="100"
            Width="210"
            WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
            ShowInTaskbar="False"
            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
            ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <TextBox HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Window>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<TextBox FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't work for me. However, the other suggestion putting this attached property in header with Binding to ElementName works for me. Without binding, it throws an exception.

Comment: For some reason doesn't work when `TextBox` is not the only control in the window.

Comment: When the TextBox is not the only control in the window/usercontrol use `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox}"` in the containing control, e.g. Grid or StackPanel

Answer (score 16):

yes you can use **FocusManager.FocusedElement** attached property.

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textBox1}"
```

Comment: there is any way, to make this without a name?

Answer (score 10):

try somethind like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication18.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525" FocusManager.FocusedElement="textcontrol">
    <Grid>
       <TextBox Name="textcontrol" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: there is any way, to make this without a name?

Comment: FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textcontrol}"

Answer (score 10):

I think binding is an overkill, Reference is more lightweight:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{x:Reference textBox1}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is there really any performance difference between this and binding?

Comment: @CodeHxr, I think the right question to ask is if there is any benefit over using a binding when really a reference is sufficient.