# Why is my WPF key binding to a navigation command not working?

Tags: wpf, xaml, key-bindings

I tried this:

```
<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" Key="Esc"/>
</Page.InputBindings>
```

And this:

```
<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack" Key="Esc"/>
</Page.InputBindings>
```

But still the navigation doesn't go back when I press escape. How do I make this key binding work?

Comment: Are you debugging this in Visual Studio?  If so, when you open up the page, do you see any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: I don't see any binding errors related to commands; I set Data Binding tracing to Information.

Comment: Actually, I believe the Key property should be `Escape` not `Esc`. Give that a try

Comment: Nope, Esc was suggested by IntelliSense, and Escape didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most probably because the page is not in focus. I guess you load the page in a frame. To check if it is generally working, click anywhere in the page and hit esc.

Possible solutions i know are:
1) use focus manager on load of page to set focus in the page (and not have focus on the window)

2) set the binding not on the page but on the window. This can be tricky architectur-wise. Because if you load different pages you have to load and unload that event if is page dependent.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I use FocusManager to set focus to the page?

Comment: by setting the focused element to any element in that page. It may be possible to set it to the page itself. see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement?view=netframework-4.7.2 and here the first two answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246554/how-to-set-autofocus-only-in-xaml

Comment: Nope, I tried `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` in the <Page> and that didn't help...

Comment: try it on a different element i.e. a textbox.

Comment: If I click a button then the key binding works; how would I bind it to a button? I tried `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=btnShipStats}` and `{Binding Path=btnShipStats}` but neither of those worked; I have to manually click the button to focus it.

Comment: Oh, I just put `btnShipStats.Focus();` in the page constructor and that worked!

Comment: if you use relative source=self, then you put it directly on the button in xaml <Button FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...> But fine that it works now!