# Focus Manager issue in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, popup, focusmanager

I have `Popup` window where dynamically attaching the `UserControl`. Here I need to set the focus for first control. If I use:

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtcode}"
```

on `UserControl`  the cursor not coming. Could anyone help me to set focus on first element in the `UserControl`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use trigger instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204063/wpf-set-focus-when-a-button-is-clicked-no-code-behind

Answer (score 0):

I have just needed to do this, but not in a user control, so might not help. what I needed to do is to add the FocusManager bit in the Window tag:

```
<Window x:Class="xxxxx"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtcode}">
```

And then make sure i correctly named the control:

```
<TextBox Name="txtcode" Text="" />
```

Although I'm new to wpf, and haven't worked with user controls yet.