# Binding FocusAction Behavior on Button Click

Tags: c#, mvvm, winrt-xaml

I am not very experienced using Behaviors, but so far they have come in handy to be able to execute code from the `ViewModel` but still triggering the actions from the `View`.

In my current scenario, I have a `TextBox` that appears when a `Button` is clicked. I would like to then set the focus of that `TextBox` *after* the `Button` has been clicked.

Previously, I have been able to set the focus using an `EventTriggerBehavior` like so:

```
<core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    <behaviors:FocusAction />
</core:EventTriggerBehavior>
```

However, this will only suffice if I want to set the focus of that control when the `View` is loaded. In this case, the `TextBox` isn't visible at that time, and actually, the focus goes to a different `TextBox` initially.

Is there a way to set the focus of a control from the `ViewModel`? This is a WinRT 8.1 application, but will be being ported to Windows 10 Universal in the future.

**EDIT**

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2212927/3101082) looks like it would do what I am looking for, but when I try it I get an error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'UIPropertyMetadata'

From what I can tell, that [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uipropertymetadata(v=vs.110).aspx) exists in the `System.Windows` namespace, but even with a `using System.Windows;` I still get the same error. I have also tried `new System.Windows.UIPropertyMetadata(null, ElementToFocusPropertyChanged)` as well, but that doesn't make a difference either. Is that class not available in WinRT?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by slightly modifying the answer linked to in my original question. For anyone looking to accomplish this in a WinRT application, here is the modified code:

```
public class EventFocusAttachment
{
    public static Control GetElementToFocus(Button button)
    {
        return (Control)button.GetValue(ElementToFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetElementToFocus(Button button, Control value)
    {
        button.SetValue(ElementToFocusProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementToFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ElementToFocus", typeof(Control),
        typeof(EventFocusAttachment), new PropertyMetadata(null, ElementToFocusPropertyChanged));

    public static void ElementToFocusPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click += async (s, args) =>
            {
                var control = GetElementToFocus(button);
                if (control != null)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    control.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I had to add a small delay because the `TextBox` that I am focusing on is not visible until after the button is pressed, so it wasn't working without the delay. Also, I had to change the `UIPropertyMetadata` to simply `PropertyMetadata`, and add `async` to the lambda expression to allow for the `await Task.Delay(100);`