# Setfocus from within VM not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've following code in my WPF app.I'm trying to set the focus on a textbox on a button click...i.e. on invoking Check() method...

Code:

MainWindowResources.xaml

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="MyFiedlStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FocusOnMyField}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=myField}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Width="180" Text="{Binding MyAttributes.MyFieldValue}" TabIndex="4" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="5" 
                     Name="myField" Style="{DynamicResource MyFieldStyle}"/>
```

MainWindowViewModel

```
 private bool FocusOnMyField
        {
            get { return m_FocusOnMyField; }
            set
            {
                m_FocusOnMyField = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FocusOnMyField");
            }
        }




private void Check()
{
    this.FocusOnSecDescription = true;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: 1. There are 2 types of focus to be aware of, are you aware of that? 2. what's `FocusOnSecDescription` ? does it have anything to do with anything else ?

Comment: @Quantic i think he's talking about ViewModel, not VirtualMachine :)

Comment: @Noctis Ah, yea I think you're right. Removed that comment which is probably very confusing heh.

Comment: Your property is private. As far as I know databinding only works for public properties.

Comment: You should probably take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204063/wpf-set-focus-when-a-button-is-clicked-no-code-behind

Comment: Thanks very much Nathan.My bad..yes,after the making the property public it started working!